# Webforms Error shows TWO projects although solution shows ONE project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, webforms

In a VS-2019 webforms solution I get this error that shows TWO projects although the solution only has ONE project.
[image]
Severity:  **Error**
Code    Description : **BC30456 'prpPageCaption' is not a member of 'MasterPage'.**
Project:      **7_SessionExpired.aspx, repo_TripManagement**
File:         **C:\Users...\SessionExpired.aspx.vb**
Line:         **100**
Suppression State: **Active**

It appears that the error shows TWO projects and I did not create a project named **7_SessionExpired.aspx**

The vb-page "SessionExpired.aspx and .vb" was copied from a similar project in VS-2017.  This is confusing to me and I don't have any way to know what this error is saying.

Here is the LINE=100 from the source VB file:

```
100|  |      Master.prpPageCaption = "Session has Expired"
```

Here is the property in the master-page:

```
Public Property prpPageCaption() As String
    Get
        Return Me.lblCaption.Text
    End Get
    Set(ByVal p_sCaption As String)
        Me.lblCaption.Text = p_sCaption
        Me.updpanelPageCaption.Update()
    End Set
End Property
```

The vb-page "SessionExpired.aspx and .vb" was copied from a similar project in VS-2017.  This is confusing to me and I don't have any way to know what this error is saying.  I need your help.  Thanks...John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think the IDE/VS-2019 is confused and I cut ALL of the files for SessionExpired.aspx (.vb) and pasted them in a my-documents-folder.
I then added a webform-page with Master-page (WebForm1.aspx) into the project.
I then added the ASPX objects as UI for the page.  I performed a "View Code" option and the / VB-code structure is shown.  I only added "Option Explicit ON".  Saved both modified files and closed the SOLUTION.

I then re-opened the solution and the code compiled -- even though the full VB-functionality was not coded.
From the 'Solution Explorer' I then renamed the WebForm1.aspx to "SessionExpired" and compiled again -- all ok.

Finally I added the VB-code from the saved-off original SessionExpired.vb code.
All of the errors shown above were cleared and things are working.

IMHO, bringing in an older webform brings with it the old-style of 'designer' and by starting with a VS-2019 webform-page conforms to the VS-2019 designer pattern.

I apologize to those that viewed this question.
Thanks.   John.